# How can I wrap implicit section in HTML 5 by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, outline

HTML snippet:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
```

The snippet above is equal to:

```
<section>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
  <section>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document).

Now I want to do this by jQuery from the first snippet. Is there already an API for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/LX2YX/

```
$('h2').next('p').andSelf().wrapAll('<section />');

$('h1').next().andSelf().next().andSelf().wrapAll('<section />');
```

You can see browser inspector to check your DOM tree :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which is easy :

```
$('h1,p,h2').wrapAll('<section />');
$('h2,p:eq(1)').wrapAll('<section />');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/LX2YX/1/

**NOTE :** the selector `'p:eq(1)'` means the second `<p>` in your page